# How to Install PHP on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, apache2, php

**ORIGINAL POST**

This I would imagine is going to be a simple answer. I have Apache2 running on my Ubuntu server but it seems PHP is not installed. When I try to load a php page it does not load properly.

Example: http://urbanturtles.servegame.com/ (My Site)

At first I thought the php module was simply not loaded but when I try to run `sudo a2enmod php` but it did not work and I get this error:
`ERROR: Module php does not exist!`

Thanks for help in advance!

**EDIT**

After trying to load a simple PHP page to show the php version I have gotten a new error trying to load the page. that error is visible here: http://urbanturtles.servegame.com/version.php . This makes me think I have more of an Apache issue than a php issue. I have a main Apahce sever that proxys all incoming traffic to each server inside my network. The Apache config for the main server looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName MaxKulik.net
        ServerAdmin max@maxkulik.net
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName "www.MaxKulik.net"
        ServerAlias "MaxKulik.net"
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.5/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.5/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName MaxKulik.net
        ServerAdmin max@maxkulik.net
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName "www.MaxKulik.net"
        ServerAlias "MaxKulik.net"
        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
        ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.5/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.5.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
        ServerName USI
        ServerAdmin max@maxkulik.net
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName "www.UrbanTurtles.servegame.com"
        ServerAlias "UrbanTurtles.servegame.com"
        ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.28
        ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.28
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I added some info to the post. This is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Why is it not a duplicate?

Comment: @muru because it's not a problem with php. see OP's comment below my answer

Comment: @Vishwa I see both a problem with PHP (the link in the question) *and* a problem with whatever proxypass is being used (the link in the comment).

Comment: Is the final `.` in `https://192.168.1.5.` a typo or intentional?

Comment: It was a typo. I made the change and it has no effect - but a typo nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

from viewing your site's page source, it shows that it loaded **wp-blog-header.php** from your wordpress installation. if you still thinks something wrong with your php, do as follows

1. Create a text file, e.g. using notepad or any other text editor:

   ```
   <?php
   phpinfo();
   ?>
   ```
2. Save the file as "version.php". Make sure, that the extension is .php (not .txt)
3. Upload the file to the root of your web server
4. Open the file in your web browser, e.g. http://www.yourdomain.com/version.php

or you can install xampp or lampp as it comes with everything you need bundled

Comment: I did that and it seems that my problem may lie slightly deeper. Have a look if you'd like http://urbanturtles.servegame.com/version.php

Comment: seems like you've got something wrong with server, dns and ip. not with the php . take a look at these,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643412/dns-lookup-failed-error-with-all-browsers    and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526703/dns-lookup-failing    Also you should try on serverfault (https://serverfault.com)

Comment: I don't think it's a DNS issue. I added some info to the post. And thanks. I'll try there also.

Comment: Not a dns, but with Apache.. check on this line on your edit,  **ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.5.** is final **.** was necessary somehow? or mistake?

Comment: That was in fact a mistake. I am making that change now.

Comment: I made the change but it has no effect

Comment: You should restart apache

Comment: I have using `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Is there still a problem? Your /version.php page looks fine. And if I open your website's url I get to see the WordPress installation procedure.